# Canvas URL settings not found

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2012, facebook-apps

I am developing my first facebook app from Visual studio 2012 , I have created app in facebook now I m supposed to set canvas URL to my project URL but I am not finding any settings for canvas in basic settings tab , why is it so ? Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You check off "App on Facebook" and then it'll show you options such as "Canvas URL"